# Optimizar un reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

Hola ahorita estoy trabajando en un diagrama de una escuela (es un ejemplo no el caso real en el que lo voy a usar), la API de la escuela tiene varios datos anidados así que se hizo varios reducers para separarlos, entre ellos, un reducer para todos los maestros.

El array de maestros tiene un máximo de 20 maestros que se pueden tener(cada maestro es un objeto), y cada maestro tiene asignado un equipo/salón (osea un array) y en cada equipo se pueden hasta 4 personas(cada persona es un objeto) y se tiene registrados ciertos datos que son modificables(vease la imagen).

Ahora lo que estoy buscando hacer es buscar la forma de hacer más pequeño el reducer para que así, en el momento en que necesite acceder a una persona dentro de un salón de uno de los maestros sea lo más fácil de modificar.

Anexo código de cómo está estructurado el reducer de los maestros:

import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TeachersActions.addTeacher, TeachersActions.deleteTeacher, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    pending: true
  })),
  on(TeachersActions.getSchoolDataSuccess, (state, {school }) => ({
    ...initialState,
    teachers: school.data[DesignNumbers.ZERO]?.teachers
  })),
  on(SchoolDetailsActions.createSchoolSuccess, (state, { school }) => ({
    ...initialState,
    teachers: school.teachers
  })),
  on(TeachersActions.deleteArmSuccess, (state, { teacherId }) => ({
    ...state,
    teachers: state.teachers.filter(teacher => teacher.id !== teacherId),
    pending: false
  })),
  on(TeachersActions.addTeacherSuccess, (state, { teacher }) => ({
    ...state,
    teachers: [...state.teachers, teacher],
    pending: false
  })),
  on(TeachersActions.deleteTeacherFailure, TeachersActions.addTeacherFailure, (state, { error }) => ({
    ...state,
    pending: false,
    error
  })),
  on( SchoolDetailsActions.deleteSchoolSuccess, () => ({
    ...initialState
  }))
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?